# Changing Model associations after running migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, rails-migrations, model-associations

I have a Devise User model with the following contents for which I did run migration.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :token_authenticatable, :confirmable, :lockable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :role
  # attr_accessible :title, :body


  ROLES = ['admin', 'network/system admin', 'manager', 'programmer']

  def role?(base_role)
    ROLES.index(base_role.to_s) <= ROLES.index(role)
  end

end
```

later on , I added the below two lines to the same model and run migration for Ticket, Projects and Assignments.

```
  has_many :projects, :through => :assignments
  has_many :tickets
```

Does the above update the association of user with the Tickets and Projects? Is there any problem in changing associations in model after running migration for the same? I want to know it as I am developing a Rails app now.

Thanks :)-

Comment: Depends on what change you want to make to the associations. Could you please include some code?

Comment: I am sure I have asked a genuine and clear question. Those who are down voting please mention the reason.

Comment: @Dogbert: I have updated the question. Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

You should also have association...

```
has_many :assignments
```

in your user model.

no other updation is required.

Comment: will the association get reflected to the database?

Comment: No, as association is has_many. So, there is no database updation in users table.